# Retrieve two strings from a stored procedure result to strings

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sqlcommand

[SCHOOL WORK]

I have a stored procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [IO].[usp_selectUser] (@username varchar(50))
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT passwordSalt, hashedPassword
    FROM [IO].[Users]
    WHERE username = @username;
END
```

And in my C# program I need to get the `passwordSalt` and the `hashedPassword` where username matches:

Current C# code:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("[IO].[usp_selectUser]", con);
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@username", SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = username;
```

I've tried some stuff from Google search results, but none of the worked properly. How do I get two individual strings?

Comment: For 2 strings try output parameters.

Comment: For getting data from SQL Server has loads of tutorials out there - part of doing your homework is doing the research, not getting someone else to solve it for you.

Comment: No need to be rude, i'm not trying to weasle out.

I've tried that already, probably wrong since it is not working, here's the code:

Comment: command.Parameters.Add("@passwordSalt", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                command.Parameters.Add("@hashedPassword", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            salt = Convert.ToString(command.Parameters["@passwordSalt"].Value);
            dbhpass = Convert.ToString(command.Parameters["@hashedPassword"].Value);

Comment: In fact your previous question is virtually identical and has the same answers?

Comment: Add what you have tried to the question - not a comment.

Comment: My previous question was different, just needed one row, one column where something meets the condition, one string, used info message.

Answer (score 0):

A friend solved my problem. The stored procedure didn’t have marked parameters as output.

```
 USE [TICKETING_DB]
    GO
    /****** Object:  StoredProcedure [IO].[usp_selectUser]    Script Date: 5/4/2020 11:08:10 AM ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    ALTER PROCEDURE [IO].[usp_selectUser] (@username varchar(50), @passwordSalt varchar(50) output, @hashedPassword varchar(100) output)
    AS
    BEGIN
    SELECT @passwordSalt = passwordSalt, @hashedPassword = hashedPassword FROM [IO].[Users]
    WHERE username = @username;

    END
```